Ubuntu 24.04 gdb ".gnu_debugaltlink" missing file messages
Ubuntu 24.04, gdb 15.0.50.20240403-0ubuntu1, gcc Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4, all installed via apt from repo.
When I go into gdb (command-line or from my IDE) and run I get a whole bunch (20?) of

could not find '.gnu_debugaltlink' file for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0

messages.  This is really annoying.  It did not happen at Ubuntu 22.04.
I have Googled but not found any way to suppress these messages.  I will not have, and do not want/need, all these sundry library '.gnu_debugaltlink' files.  Is there some way/setting these messages can be made not to appear?
P.S.
As per @steeldriver's comment I already have set debuginfod enabled off as the only line in my ~/.gdbinit.  And show debuginfod gives
(gdb) show debuginfod
debuginfod enabled:  Debuginfod functionality is currently set to "off".

Mind I notice it also says
debuginfod verbose:  Debuginfod verbose output is set to 1.

Maybe that needs to be changed...?  Hmm, sadly not, just tried set debuginfod verbose 0, that takes OK but does not suppress the messages.

Have you confirmed that GDB works on Ubuntu 24.04? The maker may need to update the app. I suggest you contact them.

Pardon?  Of course gdb (it's the system/gcc debugger) works under 24.04, I am surprised at the question....

You can disable debuginfod altogether by putting set debuginfod enabled off in your init file (~/.config/gdb/gdbinit or ~/.gdbinit) - does that stop the messages?

@steeldriver I wish!  I already have set debuginfod enabled off as the only line in my ~/.gdbinit.  I trust that is getting executed?  I find (gdb) show debuginfod debuginfod enabled:  Debuginfod functionality is currently set to "off".   Are you able to actually test this (you would need some program which uses a library for which .gnu_debugaltlink file is not available)?

@JonBrave I am only able to test it to the extent that if I set it off then gdb no longer asks me if I want to Enable debuginfod for this session? when I try to debug a simple a.out that was compiled without symbols.

@steeldriver Thanks, yes, that is why I put it there in the first place previously.  I have posted some more info on this in my question.

Hmm - so I guess the debuginfod switches only affect whether it tries to download remote debug info - it still looks for local .debug files

Can you provide a MWE that reproduces the behavior? I tried creating a simple hello world ELF binary with debug symbols, moving the symbols to a separate .dbg file as described here, then removing the .dbg file - but I don't see anything more verbose from gdb than (No debugging symbols found in main).

My situation is because I write C++ applications for Qt6.  I have downloaded all qt6 stuff from Ubuntu apt.  (Qt devs are not interested in Ubuntu-bundled releases.)  All my could not find '.gnu_debugaltlink' file messages originate from those libraries or what they require.  So I don't know what I would have to do to produce a similar "missing file" outside of that.  Like I say, all I want is to suppress the messages, I'm not looking for or going to get the actual .gnu_debugaltlink files for their libraries.

OK so I managed to reproduce the issue using this glibc hello world however the only way I can find to suppress the .gnu_debugaltlink messages is by invoking gdb with the -readnever option - which presumably will prevent it from loading symbol tables from your own code as well as from libraries. It seems odd that it doesn't also complain about .gnu_debuglink, only .gnu_debugaltlink.
